# Algebraic Fukaya categories and mirror symmetry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry, mirror-symmetry, fukaya-category

Dominic Joyce and collaborators have outlined a programme to construct algebraic Fukaya categories on an algebraic symplectic manifold ([“Fukaya categories” of complex Lagrangians in complex symplectic manifolds](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/joyce/Zurichhandout.pdf)). This makes use of the derived symplectic geometry of Pantev–Toen–Vaquie–Vessozi, and the Fukaya categories include derived Lagrangians.

Because of the flexibility of derived algebraic geometry, these categories seem to avoid some of the issues of the usual Fukaya categories. In particular, transversality and Lagrangian correspondences are easier to deal with.

Do these Fukaya categories have any role to play in mirror symmetry?

For instance, on a smooth hyperkähler variety $(X, \omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3)$, one has the algebraic symplectic form $\Omega_1 = \omega_2 + i\omega_3$. Assuming one can construct the algebraic Fukaya category $\operatorname{Fuk}(X,\Omega_1)$, is it reasonable to expect this to have a mirror category $D^b(\hat{X})$ in the style of homological mirror symmetry?

In fact, in the hyperkähler case, the mirror should be a category of BBB branes, so perhaps a derived category on the twistor space of $\hat{X}$ would be a more appropriate mirror conjecture.

Comment: Not an answer, but Remark 6.15 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.3259v4 gives a fairly comprehensive summary of related results at the time, though Remark 5.12 of https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~behrend/GeBaViLa.pdf is much more cautious with terminology. For a more recent construction, there's section 5 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01000 .

Comment: See also a discussion on p.3 in the recent paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.07595

Comment: @JonPridham, Thanks for these references, this clarifies a lot. I noticed that your paper also contains the quotation marks around Fukaya categories, when referring to the algebraic constructions. Can I think of the implied skepticism essentially as the questions posed in the Remark 5.12 you reference are not yet solved -  so morphisms in the algebraic Fukaya construction are yet to be compared to Lagrangian Floer cohomologies?

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi, Thank you for this, the exposition in this reference is really helpful. Could I tempt you to share some insights from Betti/Dolbeault geometric Langlands to this question? Your algebraic model “Fuk(Higgs_G(X)) = Shv_n(Bun_G(X))” seems to undergo a mirror-like duality. Does this suggest a mirror-like relation for algebraic Fukaya categories of the Higgs moduli spaces and stacks, some form of categorisation of the duality between BBB and BAA branes conjectured by Kapustin-Witten?

Comment: @RobertHanson caution rather than scepticism, to reflect that it's named by analogy

Comment: @RobertHanson Certainly there should be some version of an equivalence of twistor categories between BAA and BBB branes on dual hyperkahler spaces like dual Hitchin systems, but I haven't seen anything close to that formulated very precisely. Short of doing something twistorial, it seems the algebraic Fukaya POV leads (modulo eg the paper I cited) to something very close to the standard versions of geometric Langlands (in particular the B-side doesn't seem to change). But yes on the dual side would be great to have a twistor category of BBB branes, we know lots of objects (eg "L-sheaves")..